# Can't connect IBOutlets in XCode Tab Bar Application

Tags: cocoa-touch, xcode, interface-builder, iboutlet

I started with a Tab Bar Application. I deleted the SecondViewController.xib and in Interface Builder I deleted the associated tab bar button. Then in XCode I created a SecondViewController and a ThirdViewController. I added two tab bar buttons in IB and made these view controllers the file owners for their respective buttons. Then in the third view I added some UITextFields and a UIButton.

I can run the program, change view, and see the things I made in each of those views. The problem is when I create IBOutlets and IBActions in ThirdViewController and go to IB to link them to the things in the third view, none of those show up, so I can't make the links to the things showing in the view. Why is that?

Comment: Please don't tag questions as [cocoa] that are specific to Cocoa Touch.

Answer (score 0):

There might be several reasons, try these ones..

Select the FilesOwner in your interface builder and try Menu > Read Class Files, point it to your Header file(s). See if you can view the IB (Select the FilesOwner / Item -> Menu > Tools > Connections Inspector.

Or You might have unsaved Header files with IBOutlets and IBActions, first try saving those